# Javascript substring() returning the wrong value from my string?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var sequence = $stateParams.testId.length == 14 ?
               parseInt($stateParams.testId.substring(11, 2)) : 0;
```

What I expect is for the sequence to be set to 01 (the last two numbers). But what happens is that it returns 198.

Can someone explain why this is?

> console.log($stateParams.testId) // "01198-05282-01"
>
> console.log(sequence) // 198

Comment: is this angular related?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS but it's just a normal javascript variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) works with the indexes.

The signature of the `substring` is

> str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])

Note that the second parameter is the index itself and not the length of the substring.

[<sup>Quoting from MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Description)

> **If `indexStart` is greater than `indexEnd`, then the effect of `substring()` is as if the two arguments were swapped; for example, `str.substring(1, 0) == str.substring(0, 1)`.**

So,

`.substring(11, 2)` is equivalent to `.substring(11, 2)` which will give the substring `"198-05282-"` and using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on it will give the output as `198`.

1. Use the second param as index, here, 14(12 + 2)
2. Use the *radix* parameter to `parseInt` as 10 to avoid unexpected results

**Code:**

```
var str = '01198-05282-01';

var sequence = str.length == 14 ?
    parseInt(str.substring(12, 14), 10) : 0;
//                             ^^   ^^

console.log(sequence);
```

---

To get the substring using the `length`, use [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
str.substr(12, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explaination:

Your querystring contains: `"01198-05282-01"`
Lets take it in a variable:

```
var a= "01198-05282-01";
```

If we substring it,

```
a.substring(11,2)
```

It will return:

```
"198-05282"
```

You have parseInt in your code, hence

```
parseInt("198-05282");
```

will return

```
198
```

> The **substring()** method returns a subset of a string between one
>   index and another, or through the end of the string.

So to get the desired output you need to,

```
var a= "01198-05282-01";

console.log(a.substring(12,14))  //returns "01"
```

with `parseInt(a.substring(12,14),10) //will return 1`

With your code:

```
var sequence = $stateParams.testId.length == 14 ?
               parseInt($stateParams.testId.substring(12, 14), 10) : 0;
```

As

More about substring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

As Tushar suggessted use radix as second parameter with `parseInt`

The **parseInt**() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

> **radix**:  An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string.
>   Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans.
>   Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
>   guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
>   different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting
>   the value to 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `substring()` is well-explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35533254/2025923). If you want to get the last number after `-`, you can use regex.

```
/\d+$/
```

**Code:**

```
var str = "01198-05282-01";

var sequence = (str.match(/\d+$/) || [])[0] || 0; // Get the last number, use 0 as default if not present
sequence = parseInt(sequence, 10);
```

---

**What's wrong with `substring()`?**

There's nothing wrong in using `substring()` but it has following limitations.

1. It's **static** - numbers `12` and `14`. One more thing to keep track of.
2. If there are non-numeric characters at the position from 12 to 14, the result will be unexpected. However, using RegEx will give the accurate result, zero when string not end with numbers.